# Is there a 5% range CO sensor with a response rate higher than 1Hz?

Tags: electrical-engineering, measurements, sensors, gas

I'm building a portable emission analyser which measures emissions from a tailpipe, to aid in troubleshooting and tuning an engine. For this, I need a $\text{CO}_{2}$ , a $\text{CO}$, and an $\text{O}_{2}$ sensor.

While these sensors are widely available, I am in search for the type of sensor that has the lowest response time, while being able to measure in the range of 5-10% (gas dilution is not an option for my application). I already found a $\text{CO}_{2}$  and an $\text{O}_{2}$ sensor that are able to do so, but I can't find a $\text{CO}$ sensor with these capabilities.

Those all seem to have a response-time of around 30 seconds, and most are only able to measure up to around 2000ppm. I need a sensor as fast as 1 second or faster and able to measure at least 5% $\text{CO}$.

So, Is there a $\text{CO}$ sensor on the market that is able to measure in the range of 5%, while responding within 1 second?

Comment: I'm afraid that [shopping questions are off-topic here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I get the rules about shopping, but i'm not asking for a recommendation or other subjective answer here.(ie. in the main question) I need a sensor with certain capabilities and i'm asking if anyone knows if there's such a sensor available.

Comment: To improve the chance of your question to survive the close vote, I removed the really shopping-like part from the end. If it really conflicts with your intent, feel free to put it back.

Comment: @Bart - exactly, you're asking if such a sensor is on the market. That's a shopping question. After all, an answer that just said "yes" would be useless to you and anyone else reading the question.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena Nope, there doesn't seem to be one, let alone meeting the requirements i'm looking for.